# javascript concat without string concat function not working properly

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I am working with loop in javascript. I need to display some JavaScript variable with HTML tag. Here is my script.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
document.write("<p style='background:>XYZ</p>");
}
```

Here result variable is used to store different color-code array(#FFFFFF,000000 etc). Now i want to display value of result like `document.write("<p style='background:result[i]>XYZ</p>");` Here result variable have some color-code to display background style proper and it'll display as i need.

Comment: You say not working properly. What happens. Please explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for string concatenation:

```
document.write("<p style='background:" + temp + "'>XYZ</p>");
```

Also note that I fixed the ending `'` and `>` for you, you had them in the wrong place.

You don't need `temp` at all, of course:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    document.write("<p style='background:" + result[i] + "'>XYZ</p>");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var result = [
  'green', 'blue', 'yellow'
];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    document.write("<p style='background:" + result[i] + "'>XYZ</p>");
}
```

It wasn't clear to me whether `XYZ` was meant to be text, or represent the `temp` variable. If it was meant to represent the `temp` variable, just remove it from the above.

---

Side note: `document.write` is a very, very primitive mechanism, and if you use it after the initial page load, you'll wipe out the page. Look into the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) instead, or (as you've tagged your question `jquery`), the various jQuery features like [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append).

Answer (score 0):

In JS we concat string literals with `+`:

```
document.write("<p style='background:"+ temp +"'>XYZ</p>");
```